# Connect to Redis Cache Azure in ASP.NET 5 (ASP.NET Core 1.0)

Tags: c#, azure, caching, redis, asp.net-core

I'm trying to connect to Redis Azure. I have read it [this article](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cache-dotnet-how-to-use-azure-redis-cache/) and see the [examples in the official Repo](https://github.com/aspnet/Caching/tree/dev/samples).

I have this code:

```
var cache = new RedisCache(new RedisCacheOptions
            {
                Configuration = "mysamplecache.redis.cache.windows.net,port: 6380,ssl = true,ConnectTimeout = 10000,abortConnect=false"
            });
```

But it's not working... I don't know how to put the connection string and password, and InstanceName parameter...

I'm using this package:

```
"Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Redis": "1.0.0-*"
```

The error:

> RedisConnectionException: No connection is available to service this
>   operation: EVAL

What is the correct way?

Thanks!!

Comment: Do you want to use that with the built-in Dependency Resolver? Did you set the ServiceDescription for the RedisCacheOptions and did you register IDistributedCache?

Comment: I would like to use with uilt-in Dependency Resolver. I think I don't know how to register the IDistributedCache. A full example will be great ;) Thanks

Comment: https://github.com/joaquin-corchero/MVC6RedisSessionAndCache/blob/master/src/MVC6RedisSessionAndCache.Web/Startup.cs

Comment: password should be in the connection string (Configuration). You can pretty much copy&paste it from AccessKeys panel in Azure, e.g. "bla.redis.cache.windows.net:6380,password=***,ssl=True,abortConnect=False"